# PHP update big CSV files efficently

Tags: php, arrays, csv, bigdata

so basically my objective here is pretty simple. I have an big CSV inventory file with about 400k lines/items and I am receiving a csvstock file every couple minutes. I am trying to find an efficent and fast way to transfer the new stock count from the gathered stock-feed and update the stock on my inventory file. I created an array from the stock-feed, looping trough my inventory csv file and if the sku from the stock-feed matches with a sku of my inventory file, I am replacing the stock count from the stock-feed to my inventory file.

But the efficency here is really bad, takes years to update those 400k lines.

Any idea for a good efficent way to update my inventory csv with the data from my stock-feed?
Maybe PHP is not the right to work here with, if so, any other tips on how to handle it fast and efficient ?

That is my stinky code so far:

```
<?php
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('stock-feed.csv') , [","]);
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}

$row = 1;
$filedone = fopen("updatedStockInventory.csv", "w");

$fileName = "Inventory.csv";

$file = fopen($fileName, "r");

while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, "|")) !== false)
{

    if ($row == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $key = array_search($column[2], array_column($csv, 'sku'));
        $stock = $csv[$key]['stock'];
        if ($key != "")
        {
         //Write line with new stock count  
        }
        else
        {
         //skip
        }

        fputs($filedone, $line);

    }
    $row++;
}

?>
```

Comment: You didn't tell us how many lines there are in the updates. Have you considered putting the inventory in a database and then update the database? Whenever the inventory is needed you can export it from the database.

Comment: There are a number of things you can try (e.g., leave the import continually running w/ the entire CSV file in memory) but you're pretty much at the point where you really need to be considering a proper database. Heck, even SQLite would work better than such a large CSV.